# Trying to create a dropdown menu with @media screen and hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust the layout of my website depending on the size of the screen. I want my buttons with images inside them to have dropdown menus when you hover over them, however I am putting the class name `dropdown-btn` and then hover, yet it doesn't respond. Is it some syntax error?

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1900px) {
  .sidenav{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .sidenav-free-text{
    display: none;
  }
  .dropdown-container {
    display: none;
  }
  .dropdown-btn:hover .dropdown-container a{
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .dropdown-btn{
    width: 8.87%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .dropdown-btn img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .dropdown-container {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="sidenav">
    <div class="sidenav-free-text">
    <p>text.</p>
    </div>
    <a onclick="PlayMusicFinishedHTML('Home')" onmouseover="playMusicHover()" >Microsoft και MS-DOS (1974-1981)</a>
    <button class="dropdown-btn"><img src="../../../images\Windows banners\Windows1.0.png" alt="win1.0"   onclick="PlayMusicFinishedHTML()" onmouseover="playMusicHover()"> 
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a onclick="PlayMusicFinishedHTML('Windows DR5')" onmouseover="playMusicHover()">Windows DR5 (01/11/1984)</a>
      <a onclick="PlayMusicFinishedHTML('Windows PRE')" onmouseover="playMusicHover()">Windows Premiere Edition (30/07/1985)</a>
      <a onclick="PlayMusicFinishedHTML('Windows 1.04')" onmouseover="playMusicHover()" style="background-image: radial-gradient(circle, red, green, blue, yellow);">Windows 1.04 (08/04/1987)</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: css will eb read from top to bottom. So you have a :hover css defintion to `display: block` while later on a `display: none`. That display none will overwrite the hover as it will eb read last and will eb the "Newest" styling command.

Comment: i tried removing it and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your code, I'll cover each individually.

1. `(min-width: 1900px)`

This reads as "apply the following styles when the page width is at least 1900px wide". Meaning you have to have a *really* wide browser to see the styles applied. I believe you have this backwards, and want to apply styles when the screen is small. You can do this simply by changing the media query to use `max-width` instead.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
```

2. The selector `.dropdown-btn:hover .dropdown-container a`

A couple things here. `.dropdown-container` is a *sibling* of `.dropdown-btn`, not a child. You also hide `.dropdown-container`, not the `a` elements. Use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) and apply styles to the dropdown-container instead:

```
.dropdown-btn:hover + .dropdown-container { }
```

With those changes I believe you will be closer to what you had in mind. Note that I simplified your HTML a bit just for ease of reading.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .sidenav {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .sidenav-free-text {
    display: none;
  }
  .dropdown-container {
    display: none;
  }
  .dropdown-btn:hover + .dropdown-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdown-btn {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .dropdown-btn img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .dropdown-container {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <div class="sidenav-free-text">
    <p>text.</p>
  </div>
  <a>Microsoft και MS-DOS (1974-1981)</a>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Hover me</button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a>Windows DR5 (01/11/1984)</a>
    <a>Windows Premiere Edition (30/07/1985)</a>
    <a style="background-image: radial-gradient(circle, red, green, blue, yellow);">Windows 1.04 (08/04/1987)</a>
  </div>
</div>
```